# How to keep temporary output files in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm writing a map only sparkSQL job which looks like

```
val lines = sc.textFile(inputPath)    
val df = lines.map { line => ... }.toDF("col0", "col1")
df.write.parquet(output)
```

As the job takes quite a long time to compute, I would like to save and keep the results of the tasks which successfully terminated, even if the overall job fails or gets killed.

I noticed that, during the computation, in the output directory some temporary files are created. 
I inspected them and noticed that, since my job has only a mapper, what is saved there is the output of the successful tasks.
The problem is that the job failed and I couldn't analyse what it could compute because the temp files were deleted.

Does anyone have some idea how to deal with this situation?

Cheers!

Comment: I think you should split your flow to two stages. First should compute and save and next stages should use prepared result from files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @krynio. The problem is that I cannot split the computation I do on each line. The number of partitions to process is really large, the job runs for 1 day, and waiting for one day to get no result would be pretty bad :( having a partial output would be already something...

Comment: Can you describe your environment? Like what is the size of your cluster, how many files do you have and how big they are? Nevertheless those questions will not help your original question, may help to speed up spark.

Comment: Thanks @FurkanVarol I'll provide full context then: I have to download ~3 millions web resources. Each line of the file is an URL. Overall the file is not that big but the HTTP requests take quite a while. I'm currently running in local mode on a machine with 24 cores. The map operation is, actually a mapPartition, which I use to exploit the transparent keep-alive mechanism of java. I'm not sure it's the best way to achieve my goal but It's the only which came into my mind. I was using many partitions to see some progress in the computation and hopefully have some intermediate result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the output committer to `DirectParquetOutputCommitter`.

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class", "org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.DirectParquetOutputCommitter"
```

Note that if you've turned on speculative execution, then you have to turn it off to use a direct output committer.